# Changing x axis scale on the fly

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following gnuplot script to plot data from a set of files that are being added to constantly, once every five minutes:

```
set terminal x11 size 1900, 900
# The plot will not jump to the current window on update.
set term x11 1 noraise
set obj 1 rectangle behind from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgbcolor "black"
set grid lc rgb "white"

set key left top
set key textcolor rgb "white"

set border lc rgb "white"

set xtics textcolor rgb "white"
set xtics font "Times,12"
set xtics 1
set xlabel "Hours" textcolor rgb "white"

set ytics textcolor rgb "white"
set ytics font "Times,12"
set ytics 5
set ylabel "Hits" textcolor rgb "white"

set yrange [0:50]
set y2tics font "Times,10"
set y2tics 1                  # Figures on the right side of the plot as well
set y2range [0:50]

plot "/tmp/Stats/One" using ($1)/(12.):2 title "One" with lines, "/tmp/Stats/Two" using ($1)/(12.):2 title "Two" with lines, "/tmp/Stats/Three" using ($1)/(12.):2 title "Three" with lines
pause 300
reread
```

The tics in the x axis correspond to hourly intervals. This works fine, until the script has been running for a day or so - at which point the tics in the x axis start to look a bit cluttered.

Would it be possible to change this dynamically from within the gnuplot script itself? The idea is that if the script has been running for more than, say, half a day, the tics in the x axis should be present once every two hours, rather than once every hour. And possibly other similar changes later on - e.g. after one week, there should be one tic per day. The text label would have to change consequently.

Is gnuplot capable of this, or are we talking about a shell script-driven approach instead? The latter is obviously possible, but it would be more cumbersome.

Comment: You are explicitly setting `set xtic 1`. The more data you have the more crowded it will get. If you skip this line, gnuplot should set auto xtics. Check `help xtic`. By the way, how does your data look like? Has it a timestamp or just a line number or nothing and you know one line corresponds to 5 minutes? Please show some example data.

Comment: Actually, your suggestion of commenting out the set xtic 1 line goes a long way to doing what I want. Thank you. As for my data, they are read from a file that consists of a timestamp in blocks of five minutes, starting from 0 and incremented by one every time (this would be the x coordinate) followed by a space and a value that represents the y coordinate. Every time a new such line is appended to the file I just plot that point and join it to the previous one with a line.

Comment: Ok, so every new line is another 5 minutes. So, it seems you are only interested in minutes (or hours) after start, not in absolute date/time. What if for some reason a line was maybe not written, then an absolute date might be better. Anyway, is the problem solved?

Comment: The sources of data to be plotted are reset after one week - I am plotting up to 2016 points and then restarting anew. With xtic set to 1, and each tick representing one hour, things will get quite cluttered in the x axis about a couple of days. Removing the xtic setting gets around this, allowing gnuplot to do the scaling dynamically as necessary, relabeling tics consequently - I'll have tics every hour at first, then every two hours, then every five hours, and so on. I would say that this does what I want - so, problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: If this solved the problem then please accept the answer indicating that your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SO-rule "no answer in comments"...

With the line `set xtics 1` you are explicitely setting the xtic interval to 1,
hence not allowing gnuplot to automatically decide which tic interval seems reasonable.
Check `help xtics`.

Remove the line:

```
set xtics 1
```

or
replace it by

```
set xtics auto
```